# I bought a WordPress theme from a person claiming to hold a developer license

Tags: wordpress, web-development, legal, theme

I bought a WordPress theme from a person claiming to hold a developer license, but, later I found that he didn't have the developer license.  He had purchased it as a basic license.

Can this impact my theme in terms of licensing issues? What if the theme maker finds this? Is there a way to get caught?

I know this is a common practice on the web, but wanted to make sure that i am using the right things on my site.

Comment: Who is the original developer of the theme?

Comment: Is the developer's license for the Theme or WordPress? If it is for  WordPress, there is no such thing with it being free and open source. Who did he and you buy the theme from? A developer's license on a theme? That sounds a little strange to me. Usually, once you buy a template it is yours to use from people, but this case of yours is throwing me off.

Comment: its very simple, for example, you are a designer and offer my a premium theme in $X saying that you have a developer's license of the theme, and i buy it from you, but after some time i get to know that he is not having the dev license but had just purchased a basic license (which can be used on a single site)...so, now, what could be the possible outcomes of this scene in respect to the designer and me??

Comment: i think, you all are behaving like super man here. Some one voted down even my question.why don't you leave some room for new people like me OR make it mandatory to clear a test to be eligible to ask help in this forum. I thought, i would learn something from here. But, the way you treat newbies is quite different even from other reputed forums..

Answer (score 2):

1. Purchase the correct license.
2. Send the developer a bill (or get them to trade work in kind).
3. Hope for the best and move on

Asking if there is "a way to get caught?" on a website populated by people trying to make a living on the web is bad form, at the very least. Wordpress themes, even the silly expensive ones, aren't that expensive. If you can't afford the $39-$99 bucks for your site, the theme isn't your problem.

Comment: "Send the developer a bill?" and it's not about being able to spend  $39-99 bucks..you mshould know i already gave 2-3 times more to the designer..this is a common practice poeple who don't know about themes, designing they get this work done from other designers and i just did that..